# Reading date from UTF-8 file

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to open UTF-8 file as

```
f = codecs.open(filename, "r", "utf-8")
```

This file contains dates string on each line. I can read the line from the file but when I try to format the date string using,

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, "%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M %p")
```

I get the following error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u200e' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

When I look at the value of mydate using debugger it is `unicode: ‎7/‎16/‎2014 ‏‎2:29 PM`

Comment: You've got a whole bunch of hidden unicode characters in there `>>> print repr(mydate)
u'unicode: \u200e7/\u200e16/\u200e2014 \u200f\u200e2:29 PM'`. Are you sure the file is really encoded with `utf-8`?

Comment: I exported these value to an UTF-8 file from AutoIt. I am trying to read the same file from python. When I right click on the file and see the encoding in eclipse, it shows me Inherited from container Cp 1252. But if I paste the same file in some other project, it shows UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is `utf-8` encoded:

`datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate.decode("ascii",errors="ignore"), "%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M %p")`

If not, use:

`datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate.encode("utf8").decode("ascii",errors="ignore"), "%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M %p")`